# tcl/tk GUI macOS speech to text (dictation)

Tags: macos, tcl, speech-recognition, tk-toolkit

I am working on my Tcl/Tk GUI (written through Tcl::pTk in Perl). Am I correct that Tcl/Tk widgets (entry, text, etc.) can not take as input the Speach to Text (Dictation) input of macOS (HighSierra)? I can input in pretty any software I have installed on my computer, exept from my own GUI and another software written in Tcl/Tk. Is there anything I can do, or I just have to accept it as not possible to achive?

Cheers
Kelly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the widget demos for both Tcl/Tk and Tcl::pTk (which is something I've been doing rather often to check if an issue is in Tcl/Tk or just Tcl::pTk). I'm using Tk 8.6.8 on macOS 10.13.6 (note that recent macOS comes with an older version of Tcl/Tk: 8.5.9 on macOS 10.13).

I'm able to press <kbd>fn</kbd> twice to dictate into Tcl/Tk text and entry demos just fine:

[image: Tcl/Tk entry demo]

But for the Tcl::pTk demos, I can't get it to work for an entry widget, and it's difficult to get it to work for a text widget (sometimes the dictation balloon doesn't show up on the first try, or if I focus on another text widget, then the dictation balloon might appear for that other widget instead).

[image]

Sometimes the dictation balloon shows up for ROText widgets, which doesn't cause anything to get typed, but still isn't ideal.

I'm not sure what's preventing dictation from working in Tcl::pTk, but since this is a rather basic accessibility feature, it would be great if it worked. This would be good for a bug report/feature request for Tcl::pTk.

**Update:** I've since observed difficulty using dictation even in pure Tcl/Tk examples, so I've opened a ticket: https://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview/fdbdcc8c3c

Comment: For reference, the asker has opened a ticket for this: https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=125987